# How to subtract values within a hierarchical/multi-level index in Pandas within the same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, multi-index

I am attempting to find the change in time within a specific session (my index)--my data frame looks like this:

```
                        time
sess_id     vis_id      

id1         vis_id1      t_0
            vis_id1      t_1
            vis_id1      t_2

id2         vis_id2      t_0
            vis_id2      t_1
            vis_id2      t_2
```

I want to create a column called `delta_t` (change in time) which subtracts the time stamps recursively--where the last time for every session contains filler character like a dash or something

```
                        time      delta_t
sess_id     vis_id      

id1         vis_id1      t_0     (t_1 - t_0) 
            vis_id1      t_1     (t_2 - t_1)
            vis_id1      t_2         - 

id2         vis_id2      t_3     (t_4 - t_3)
            vis_id2      t_4     (t_5 - t_4)
            vis_id2      t_5         -
```

Comment: kindly provide reproducible example, with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can [`groupby shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) relative to `level=0` or `level="sess_id"` to get the next row's value, and subtract from `time`:

```
df['delta_t'] = df.groupby(level='sess_id')['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']
```

Sample DataFrame and output:

```
                               time         delta_t
sess_id vis_id                                     
id1     vis_id1 2021-01-11 00:00:00 6 days 04:27:31
        vis_id1 2021-01-17 04:27:31 4 days 03:45:26
        vis_id1 2021-01-21 08:12:57             NaT
id2     vis_id2 2021-01-28 15:18:32 7 days 17:57:56
        vis_id2 2021-02-05 09:16:28 4 days 01:41:58
        vis_id2 2021-02-09 10:58:26             NaT
```

We *could* [`groupby diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) then [`groupby shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) but this involves 2 groupbys:

```
df['delta_t'] = (
    df.groupby(level='sess_id')['time'].diff()
        .groupby(level='sess_id').shift(-1)
)
```

---

If needing '-' over `NaT` [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) can be used to covert Timedelta to string and fillna with '-':

```
# Calculate Delta
df['delta_t'] = df.groupby(level='sess_id')['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']
# Change dtype and add in '-'
df['delta_t'] = np.where(df['delta_t'].notna(), df['time'].astype(str), '-')
```

Alternatively can convert to `str` and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) "NaT" with "-":

```
# Calculate Delta, convert to String, replace "NaT" with "-"
df['delta_t'] = (
        df.groupby(level='sess_id')['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']
).astype(str).replace('NaT', '-')
```

`df`:

```
                               time          delta_t
sess_id vis_id                                      
id1     vis_id1 2021-01-11 00:00:00  6 days 04:27:31
        vis_id1 2021-01-17 04:27:31  4 days 03:45:26
        vis_id1 2021-01-21 08:12:57                -
id2     vis_id2 2021-01-28 15:18:32  7 days 17:57:56
        vis_id2 2021-02-05 09:16:28  4 days 01:41:58
        vis_id2 2021-02-09 10:58:26                -
```

---

DataFrame constructor and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'time': pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-11 00:00:00', '2021-01-17 04:27:31',
                             '2021-01-21 08:12:57', '2021-01-28 15:18:32',
                             '2021-02-05 09:16:28', '2021-02-09 10:58:26'])},
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((['id1'] * 3 + ['id2'] * 3,
                                     ['vis_id1'] * 3 + ['vis_id2'] * 3),
                                    names=['sess_id', 'vis_id'])
)
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the swift response. Much appreciated

Comment: Working well so far..I am getting negative delta ts so I think I need to sort by time 

Is there a specific way I should order the values? I was thinking just by the time but im also getting values on the delta t on some of the last roes for every session id

Comment: If you're sorting to avoid negative deltas you should sort _before_ you subtract. `df = df.sort_values('time')` before subtracting, then `df = df.sort_index()` after subtraction to get back in order.

Comment: `df['delta_t'] = df.sort_values(by = 'time').groupby(level = 'sid')['time'].shift(-1) - df['time']`

gives me the following error: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!


edit: ill try your code above rn

Comment: Hey! I know this is super random but I was wondering if you could help me with the most recent question I posted? Seems right up your alley/similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

@Henry Ecker beat me to it but here is my answer:

```
t = [
    {'idx1': 'id1', 'idx2':         'vis_id1',    'val':  1},
    {'idx1': 'id1', 'idx2':         'vis_id2',    'val':  2},
    {'idx1': 'id1', 'idx2':         'vis_id3',    'val':  3},
    {'idx1': 'id2', 'idx2':         'vis_id4',    'val':  4},
    {'idx1': 'id2', 'idx2':         'vis_id5',    'val':  5},
    {'idx1': 'id2', 'idx2':         'vis_id6',    'val':  6},
]
df = pd.DataFrame(t).set_index(['idx1', 'idx2'])

(df
 .reset_index()
 .groupby('idx1')
 .apply(lambda df: df
        .set_index('idx2')
        .sort_index()
        .pipe(lambda df: 
              pd.Series(
                  data=df['val'].pipe(lambda s: s.iloc[1:].values - s.iloc[:-1].values).tolist() + ['-'], 
                  index=df.index
              )
       )
))
```

Here is the output:

```
idx1  idx2   
id1   vis_id1    1
      vis_id2    1
      vis_id3     -
id2   vis_id4    1
      vis_id5    1
      vis_id6     -
```

I think Henry's is more complete, though, as mine doesn't work if the ids in the second are the same, as in your example.

However, I would point out that from a data indexing perspective, it's bad practice to have multiple rows indexed by the same (multi) id.